# How to convert string into 2-dimension array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

In order to convert string into 1-dimensional JavaScript array I could use 'eval()'. But how to convert string into 2-dimensional array?

My string is:

```
['stage 1', 1, 11, 111],['Stage 2', 2, 22, 222]
```

Execution "eval(...)" with such parameter creates a 1 array with 4 elements: ['stage', 1, 11, 111]. Instead I would like to have array of 2 elements, where each element in turn is another array of 4 elements.

I believe, I could split original string by ',' into list of substrings and call 'eval' for each of them and combine the result into a 2-dimensional array.

But **I believe that more efficient way should already exist. Is there any? If yes, please advise.**

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Just wrap in an outer pair of braces: `'[' + string + ']'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `eval` it would be better to use `JSON.parse`:

```
var string = '["stage 1", 1, 11, 111],["Stage 2", 2, 22, 222]';
var array2d = JSON.parse("[" + string + "]");
console.log(array2d);
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/y94zz/

Comment: "Better" is relative, why is it better than `eval`? A JSON.parse shim will use `eval` anyway.

Comment: Why would you use `eval` when a much better method such as `JSON.parse` already exist? With `eval` in used, you cannot even minify your code by any standard minifier/compiler!

Comment: @RobG - All major browsers now support `JSON.parse`, there are shims which do not use `eval` (for example Crockford's own [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) - see `json_parse.js` or `json_parse_state.js`) and `JSON.parse` is much safer to use than `eval` since it won't execute arbitrary code nor modify variables in the calling context.

Comment: @AaditMShah—good to see an explanation. Crockford dislikes `eval` so much he wrote a parser, good for him. :-)

Comment: Additional thing: in the original source string the quotes for text should be double quotes, not single (as in my case). But solution helped, thanks a lot!